# Как в Django настроить urls.py в случае с одинаковыми адресами запроса?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-urls

Мне надо сделать два запроса с помощью Django. К проекту подключена база данных с городами, улицами, и магазинами. Запросы следующие:

- `POST /shop/` - создание магазина
- `GET /shop/?street=&city=&open=` - вывод данных

Мой код в `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('shop/', views.Getshop),
    path('shop/', views.Shopcreate),
]
```

Работа с строковым запросом и извлечением параметров идёт на ура, но выполняется только один запрос. Как отличить вышеуказанные два запроса друг от друга?

Вот мой код в `views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import *
from .models import City
from .models import Street
from .models import Shop
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def Shopcreate(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Shop create</h2>")

def Getshop(request):
    street = request.GET.get("street", -1)
    city = request.GET.get("city", -1)
    open = request.GET.get("open", -1)
    if open == "1":
        shops = Shop.objects.filter(shop_city_id=city, shop_street_id=street, shop_time_to_open__lte=timezone.now(),
                                    shop_time_to_close__gte=timezone.now())
    else:
        shops = Shop.objects.filter(shop_city_id=city, shop_street_id=street, shop_time_to_open__gt=timezone.now(),
                                    shop_time_to_close__gt=timezone.now())
    return render(request, "getshops.html", {"shops": shops})
```

Как правильно написать файл `urls.py`, чтобы запросы отличались между собой, будучи похожими по написанию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиск соответствия url-паттернов идет сверху вниз. То есть в вашем случае всегда будет срабатывать верхний паттер с вызовом `views.Getshop`.

В вашем случае не требуется создавать два разных url для работы с одним и тем же паттерном. Объедините оба обработчика в один, анализируя метод передачи параметров. например:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('shop/', views.proc_shop),
]
```

```py
def proc_shop(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse("<h2>Shop create</h2>")
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        street = request.GET.get("street", -1)
        city = request.GET.get("city", -1)
        open = request.GET.get("open", -1)
        if open == "1":
            shops = Shop.objects.filter(shop_city_id=city, shop_street_id=street, shop_time_to_open__lte=timezone.now(),
                                        shop_time_to_close__gte=timezone.now())
        else:
            shops = Shop.objects.filter(shop_city_id=city, shop_street_id=street, shop_time_to_open__gt=timezone.now(),
                                        shop_time_to_close__gt=timezone.now())
        return render(request, "getshops.html", {"shops": shops})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Скорее всего я что-то неправильно сделал. Вставил код из вашего ответа и попытался отправить запрос через браузер
 [ссылка]http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/?street=1&city=1&open=1
Выдало следующую ошибку: AttributeError at /shop/

'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Мой косяк. Я задублировал названием функции название класса модели. Сейчас поправлю код.

Comment: Бывает. А как отправить POST запрос, не подскажете? Буду очень признателен вам

Comment: Я обычно сперва отлаживаю форму создания, которая именно POST и отправляет. Возможно есть какие-то расширения разработчиков под Chrome/Firefox. Но я не заморачивался

Comment: В любом случае спасибо вам за отклик

Comment: Спасибо здесь принято выражать в лайках и пометкой правильного ответа